# abort both jquery long polling and php

Tags: php, long-integer, polling

I'm using long polling with jquery. I can abort any ajax requests by simple doing ajax_request.abort(), but what should i do to stop PHP process running which was called by ajax call?

p.s. my while loop has rescrictions, but somtimes i just need to stop everything.

Answer (score 0):

In your php process loop - put something that will abort the loop after a certain timeout/condition? Ideally it shouldn't be a blocking loop otherwise it will be more of a pain..

Failing that - the max_execution_time should kick in and kill the process?

Comment: After some time php process stops, but is there any way to stop both jquery ajax (i know how to do it) and php loop at any momment?

Comment: the way i'd do it, is to send a request down the long polled connection with a "kill" message that breaks the loop and kills the connection from the server end... it means you can cleanly manage it from the frontend as well.

Comment: something like while($var==true) in the poll and $var=false on the kill message?